# Bokeh server 0.11 plot on local LAN

Tags: tornado, bokeh

I tried to produce a plot on my local LAN using bokeh (raspberry pi2 kivypie 4.1.13 and bokeh 0.11). Naively, I tried

`bokeh serve --address 192.168.1.xxx timeout.py`

(timeout.py is one of the officialy [examples](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html))

However, I cannot access the content from my laptop which is connected to the same LAN ( I tried 192.168.1.xxx:5006). I do get the error `404: Not Found` which is different than those errors I get if I use the wrong port or address (This webpage is not available)

I guess I am missing something fundamental here. Can anyone please point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

I found out how it works but maybe someone might explain why. I added the address bokeh is listening to the whitelist:

`bokeh serve --address 192.168.1.xxx --host 192.168.1.xxx:5006 timeout.py`

It works also with:

`bokeh serve --host 192.168.1.xxx:5006 timeout.py`

Comment: The `--host` option tells the server to only service connections that report the given value as the `HOST` field in the HTML request header. Or in other words, if someone hits the server at `foo.com` the `HOST` header has to match `foo.com` (i.e., not be spoofed). By default, the only thing on the host whitelist is `localhost`, which is why you have to add something for `--host` in order for the Bokeh server to accept external connections.

Comment: Is is possible to define an IP range ?

Comment: You can specify as many `--host` options on the command line as you like, but there is no since option to specify a range at at once. That might make a nice feature, please make an issue on the GH issue tracker if you are inclined.